# Insert dictionary value from column according to its key into another column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key

I'm new to python and have been trying to face this wall for some time now. I'm using pandas data frames.

I have two columns:   X and Y

Situation: X is a dictionary column.
I'm trying to populate Y column with the search of a KEY value.

example: {'gender':'male','job':'carpenter'}

Goal: if 'gender' KEY is equal to 'male' then populate Y column with its
'job' value (carpenter).

thank you for your help!

Comment: pls elaborate more! is `Y` a new column you want to add? or its already have the value 'male', if so where you are planning to add `carpenter`? also, show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'gender':'male','job':'carpenter'},index=[0])
df1.assign(populate=np.where(df1.gender.eq('male'),df1.job,''))
```

out

```
 gender        job   populate
0   male  carpenter  carpenter
```